# How to deal with a few number of cluster (n<15) for nonlinear?

Tags: clustering, bootstrap, stata, nonlinear

I am currently trying to address a few number of clusters (n<15) for a nonlinear model (multinomial logit).

I have already gotten an idea from Cameron et al. (2008) for a linear model to use "wild cluster bootstrap". In Stata 18, they release a new command "wildbootstrap" for this purpose.

But, I have not found a good way for a nonlinear model.

Stata command "boottest" also provides wild cluster bootstrap, but for a nonlinear model, they said the command provide "score-based" result.

Does this "score" test produce cluster-adjusted p-value for each coefficient for a multinomial logit as "wildbootstrap" does?

I attempted to use this command like below.

> mlogit occupation age female urban, vce(cluster village)  base(1)

> boottest age, cluster(village) boottype(score)

And it gave completely different coefficients and omit the coefficient of age.
Maybe I was wrong about the usage of command, but I could not find any good examples on any website.

Could you help me out on this matter, especially how to use boottest to derive cluster-robust SE or p-value for nonlinear model?